# how to enable/disable button using for each

Tags: javascript

I want to disable decrement button when it reaches 1. At first i did it like this using jstl in jsp.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${line.quantity > 1}">
    <form method='post' action='<c:url value="decrement"/>'>
                <input type='hidden' name='productName' value='${line.product.productName}'/>
                <input type='hidden' name='id' value='${line.product.id}'/>
                <input type="submit" value="-" />
          </form>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
      <input type="button" disabled="disabled"/>
    </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

Now i am learning Javascript and tried to convert the above code to JS like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function decrementButton() {
    var x = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
    alert("Value of x = " + x);
    if ( x > 1)
    {    
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
        alert('Dont Disable');
    }
    else
    {    
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
        alert('Disable'); 
    }
        }
  </script>

</head>
<body onLoad="decrementButton();">
<h1>CART</h1>
    <c:forEach items="${cart.cartLines}" var="line">
<tr>
<td>
<form  method='post' action='<c:url value="decrement"/>'>
                <input type='hidden' name='productName' value='${line.product.productName}'/>
                <input type='hidden' name='id' value='${line.product.id}'/>
                <input id="quantity" type='text' 
                    style="width:25px;" name='quantity' value='${line.quantity}'/>
                <input  id="submit" type="submit" value="-" />
          </form>

    </td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

It works only for the first product in the cart. So how should i do it for each product in cart using javascript.

Comment: It works for only the first product in the cart. It does not work for second and other products after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify the same ID for several input, then just set all their `name` to the same value, let's say `name="myProduct"`.
Then you can achieve this with JS this way :

```
//look for all elements input with name="myProduct" instead of ById
 var productsList = document.getElementsByName('myProduct');
 //you got 1 submit button / product
 var submitButtonsList = document.getElementsByName('myProductSubmitButton');
 for (var i = 0; i <= productsList.length; i++) {

     alert("Value of productsList  = " + productsList[i].value);
     if (productsList[i].value > 1) {
         submitButtonsList[i].disabled = false;
         alert('Dont Disable');
     } else {
         submitButtonsList[i].disabled = true;
         alert('Disable');
     }
 }
```

This will loop through all products of your page, and each submit button of each product.

Comment: I changed id to name in html and tried. But now the button is not disabled. Do i have add any other thing.

Comment: Don't forget to change the button's names as well and this should work

Comment: I edited the code, tested here in **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps6L2mxq/)** and this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using jQuery, it will make all your DOM changing scripts a lot easier, simply add in the  or somewhere else before using the following function:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can use the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function decrementButton() {
      $('form').each(obj, function(){
          value = $(this).find($("#quantity")).val();
          if(value <= 1){
              $(this).find($( "#submit" )).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
           });
      }  
   }
 </script>
```